# Rewind Video in javascript and html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

Please Help me. What's wrong with my code. I have 2 video and I want is. when I scroll to second video container, the 1st video is going to **rewind**. I used playbackRate but didn't work for me anyone who can help me.? Thanks in advance.

[Here's](http://prntscr.com/gt07tg) the screen shot.

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

fraction = 0.7;
function checkScroll() {

for(var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

    var video = videos[i];

    var x = video.offsetLeft, y = video.offsetTop, w = video.offsetWidth, h = video.offsetHeight, r = x + w, //right
        b = y + h, //bottom
        visibleX, visibleY, visible;

        visibleX = Math.max(10, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
        visibleY = Math.max(10, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

        visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

        if (visible > fraction) {
            video.play();
        } else {
             video.playbackRate = 1.0;
        }

}

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

Comment: Have you tried calling video.play(); under the video.playbackRate = 1.0; line?

Comment: yes @AnthonyMcGrath.. before i use. video.pause(); and it's work fine and now i want to change na function. I want is rewind video instead of pause.

Comment: Have you tried pausing it then setting the playbackrate then calling play()? Or using -1.0 instead of 1.0 (I'm not sure if that will do anything)?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I tried it before I used -1.0 but still not work...